# How to display home button in costum actionbar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am using `NavigationDrawer` just as [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html), but I need to use costum actionbar. **In order to activate the drawer I need to use the home button** just as before I use costum view. When using custom actionbar, actionmenu is displayed well, but I cannot display home button. I am targeting 13 and 13+ apis, so the code I have used is below:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar);
```

the actionbar.xml is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="24sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Well I might just add a button there but I am being lazy here, and saving that option as a last resort.

### Update:

When I use `NavigationDrawer` without custom view, I get #1 as actionbar.

[image: ActionBar]

When I use `NavigationDrawer` with custom view, I get #2 as actionbar.
What I want is to get #4 as actionbar.

PS: #3 is not included in the custom view, it is created via `onCreateOptionsMenu`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution for this problem is to go not lazy and implement the home button(and #3 for some reason).

actionbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/ulak_blue" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="24sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/leftButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/rightButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

on in `onCreate` method of the activity

```
    mLeftButton = findViewById(R.id.leftButton);
    mRightButton = findViewById(R.id.rightButton);
    mLeftButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mSideMenuDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mSideMenuList)) {
                mSideMenuDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mSideMenuList);
            } else {
                mSideMenuDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mSideMenuList);
            }
        }
    });
    mRightButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Add Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

PS: any former better solution will be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the parent in the manifest.xml?

```
<activity
        android:name=".currentActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".parentActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".parentActivity" />
</activity>
```

Comment: HomeButton while using NavigationDrawer is not meant to go anywhere, it is used for sliding NavigationDrawer. so I dont have a parent activity there. Plus, I tried you porposed solution, but it did not work. Anyway, thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

solution is very simple)
Change in your Layout

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

on this:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

it will help because your initial layout takes all visible place and there is no place for "home"

Comment: then how do I get #3 on even #2 ?

Comment: Button "plus" are already in bar. All you need is to еxplicitly specify this in your menu